# Перенос магазина на opencart на протокол https

Tags: opencart, https

Перенес интернет-магазин на open cart на протокол https, но потом обнаружил что не все страницы открываются по этому протоколу ([например](http://babybooks.com.ua/knigi-na-kartone/pervaja-kniga/)). Также [главная](http://babybooks.com.ua) страница вначале открывается без этого протокола. Но при клике уже на лого идет переход на https. Как можно перенести все страницы на этот протокол? В том числе панель администратора.

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:SSL} !=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yoursite.domain/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен редирект на https.
Как его сделать - целиком и полностью зависит от хостинга. Где-то поможет .htaccess, а где-то нет.
Там, где поможет .htaccess, тоже может быть до 5 разных вариантов написания редиректа.
Одно можно сказать точно - решение в 95% случаев есть в FAQ вашего хостинга.

А, уже видно, что сделан редирект. Ну и поставили бы решение одному из ответивших...Видно, что-то мешает...?))